# The category of finitely-generated abelian groups and homomorphisms has the CSB property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, abelian-categories

The answer is yes but I have trouble proving it.
If $G$ is a finitely-generated abelian group then $G\cong G_{\tau}\times\mathbb{Z}^g$, where $G_{\tau}$ is the subgroup of torsion. Too $H\cong H_{\tau}\times\mathbb{Z}^h$, the part of the $H_{\tau}\cong G_{\tau}$ is easy of check, my problem is proof that $g=h$.

*Definition.* A category $\mathcal{C}$ is said to have the CSB property if whenever there
is a pair of monomorphisms $f : C \rightarrow D$ and $g : D \rightarrow C$, there is an isomorphism $h: C \rightarrow D$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An injection $f:G\rightarrow H$ is an identification of $G$ with a subgroup of $H$. But any subgroup has rank at most that of the larger module, and so the rank of $G$ is at most that of $H$. This gives us $g\leq h$ and symmetrically one obtains $h\leq g$ from the other monomorphism, hence $h=g$.

As you observed, the torsion part is easy to handle (to summarize for the benefit of others: the injection must take torsion to torsion, and the torsion pieces are finite, so we get size inequalities both ways, and hence the torsion parts are the same size, which means either of the original injections is an isomorphism between them).

Together we have that the ranks are equal and the torsion subgroups are isomorphic, so by the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

Comment: but the category of the groups don´t have the CSB property, if we consider $F_2$ and $F_3$ the free groups generated by ${a,b}$ and ${x,y,z}$ $f:F_3\rightarrow F_2$; $f(x)=a^2$, $f(y)=ab$  and $f(z)=b^2$ this is a monomorphisms.

Comment: that's right, but we are only talking about abelian groups

Comment: Ok, I'm still a bit confused with your argument.

Comment: no worries, let me know if you have a question